# URL redirection in asp.net web application in server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem in my hosted application url, my application hosted in below link 
"http://www.xxxxx.com/Admin/Login.aspx"
 when i am entering this full link i can see my login page successfully loaded.i also need to see my login page while i am entering "http://www.xxxxx.com/Admin" .
I developed my application in asp.net C# is language
 i tried in my web config file

```
 <system.webServer> 
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Login.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

also tried in my global.asax file

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("/"))
                {
                    Server.Transfer("~/Login.aspx");
                }
                else if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("Admin"))
                {
                    Server.Transfer("~/Login.aspx");
                }
            }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.MapPageRoute("default0", "", "~/Login.aspx");
    }
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

How can i do url redirection, please help me. I hosted my application in my server . i can take iis and see the setting but i don't know where i need to change it for this

Comment: What you see now *while i am entering* ?

Comment: just seeing login page without any style,it loads the page but no styles are getting.

Comment: @raveeshtv It sounds like it's trying to load your CSS files from a relative path (`somepath.css`), when you navigate to `/Admin` it is trying to find your CSS files in `/Admin/somepath.css`. Your options are to either make references to the CSS absolute links (`/somepath.css` - note the `/` at the beginning) or put the CSS files relative to the `/Admin` directory as well.